# Fish Shell : Set formatted string to variable

Tags: fish, iterm2

I want to open terminal with multiple instances of same server. For example, `csshX server1 server1 server1`

I'm trying to assign the formatted list of strings to single variable and use it in `csshX`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish
set nmdat (echo 'server1 ' | string repeat -n (echo $countofinstance))
csshX $nmdat
```

But, this isn't helping. I have also tried

```
csshX (echo 'server1 ' | string repeat -n (echo $countofinstance))
```

This isn't working as well.

Answer (score 3):

`(echo $somevariable)` can be written more simply as `$somevariable`

Try this: it should pass *count* individual arguments to the command:

```sh
set server server1
csshX (string repeat -n $count -N $server\n)
```

Demo:

```sh
$ set count 5
$ set string foo

$ bash -c 'echo $#; printf \'%s\\n\' "$@"' bash (string repeat -n $count "$string ")
1
foo foo foo foo foo

$ bash -c 'echo $#; printf \'%s\\n\' "$@"' bash (string repeat -n $count $string\n)
6
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo

# with an extra newline

$ bash -c 'echo $#; printf \'%s\\n\' "$@"' bash (string repeat -n $count -N $string\n)
5
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```